# How to add data into a mysql table with Django using ”objects.create"

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I’m setting up a new website, and want to add data into mysql table,
using "objects.create" ,let user text the data ,and create into database.

like this

models

```
class Record(models.Model):
    record_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    compiler_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    store = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    goods = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    account = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'record'
```

views

```
def tech2(request):

    status_a = True

    status_check_account = True

    if request.method == 'POST':
        check_account = request.POST.get('account', '')
        check_store = request.POST.get('store', '')

        check_A = Record.objects.filter(account__exact=check_account)
        check_S = Record.objects.filter(store__exact=check_store)

        if check_A:  # 如果回傳陣列是空的
            status_a = False


        R1 = request.POST.get('account', '')
        R2 = request.POST.get('account_check', '')

        if R1 == R2:  # !=改成is not
            status_check_account = True
        else:
            status_check_account = False

        accounts = request.POST.get('account', '')
        stores = request.POST.get('store', '')
        compiler_names = request.POST.get('compiler_name ', '')
        good = request.POST.get('goods', '')
        numbers = request.POST.get('number', '')
        if status_a is True and status_check_account is True:

            Record.objects.create(goods=good, compiler_name=compiler_names, number=numbers, account=account,, store=stores)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/tech/')
```

I want to build a sells  website let use type data

tech.html

```
<p class="float">
      <label for="tech">&nbsp;B</label>
      <input type="text" name="compiler_name" required autofocus value={{ compiler_name }}>
</p>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you provided?  Are you receiving errors?

Comment: Also, you are adding to a "mysql table", not a "mysql workbench table".  mysql workbench is a GUI that is used to view mysql tables, not a database itself.

Comment: I run the code and type the data ,but it didn't read into mysql tables.